# Set all spring boot properties inside .yml file into system properties

Tags: java, spring-boot, keystore, jvm-arguments, vmargs

I am working on a spring boot project in which a lot of VM arguments are passed for the application to start i.e. cert location, specific profile types(not dev,qa, prod etc).
I am working on moving all the configuration in a default.yml file.
**Problem Statement**
The properties set in the default.yml are accessible to only environment interface of spring context i.e. org.springframework.core.env.Environment only and the **properties are not set into system properties automatically/by default**.
 I am setting the property in system by a listner **ServletContextListener** in the method **contextInitialized**.
 But I dont want to explicitly call out all properties by their name using **environment .getProperty(key)**, rather I want that all the properties available in spring context should be looped/without loop be set into system/environment variables.
**Expected Solution**
I am looking for an approach using which inside the listner method I can set all properties defined in default.yml file into system properties without accessing the properties by their name.

Below is the approach I am currently following to set active profile extracted from spring env/default.yml into system property. I don't want to get active profile or get any property from yml but want all the properties available inside .yml to be set automatically into system.

```
Optional.ofNullable(springEnv.getActiveProfiles())
            .ifPresent(activeProfiles -> Stream.of(activeProfiles).findFirst().ifPresent(activeProfile -> {
                String currentProfile = System.getProperty("spring.profiles.active");
                currentProfile = StringUtils.isBlank(currentProfile) ? activeProfile : currentProfile;
                System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", currentProfile);
            }));
```

Answer (score 0):

you might use something like this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.MapPropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.util.Properties;

@Component
public class EnvTest {

    final StandardEnvironment env;

    @Autowired
    public EnvTest(StandardEnvironment env) {
        this.env = env;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void setupProperties() {
        for (PropertySource<?> propertySource : env.getPropertySources()) {
            if (propertySource instanceof MapPropertySource) {
                final String propertySourceName = propertySource.getName();
                if (propertySourceName.startsWith("applicationConfig")) {
                    System.out.println("setting sysprops from " + propertySourceName);
                    final Properties sysProperties = System.getProperties();

                    MapPropertySource mapPropertySource = (MapPropertySource) propertySource;
                    for (String key : mapPropertySource.getPropertyNames()) {
                        Object value = mapPropertySource.getProperty(key);
                        System.out.println(key + " -> " + value);
                        sysProperties.put(key, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and of course, please remove the stdout messages when it's working for you

Comment: Hi Meisch, Thanks for your answer. I ended up doing something similar :)